# 360video - POV Learning Scenarios

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording, production, 360video

I'm working for an educational facility for social workers and have a project to shoot 2  scenarios, of physical escalation with therapists and patients with cognitive disabilities, in POV.

The requirement of those scenarios are that the viewer should be able to select which subject he wants to follow.

→ So I thought 360 video would be easy. Problem: the subjects are getting into each other's hands. Meaning - there can't be a camera between them.

→ Now I'm more thinking of POV and shoot the scene twice. Once from the patient's perspective and once from the therapist.
Probably with the camera attached to a helmet (something like [this](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1660202-REG/tilta_ta_hr_l_v_hermit_pov_support_system.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw2bmLBhBREiwAZ6ugo0AsONPZoNVr6HAaIeV5wfRwu-rnTQ9EnPmYnet0KaGLFsHIY3cwMBoC4nIQAvD_BwE)).

Does anybody have experience with a shoot similar to this and can give me some advice?

The helmet is pricey, and I couldn't find a rental place for that - any other good solutions?

Thanks!